# Flutter how to add items in list

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code

```dart
    class _VariantsState extends State<Variants> {
      List<VariantDetails> variantsList = [];
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        variantsList.clear();
      }
      
         return Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 5,
            margin:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, bottom: 40.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10, bottom: 5.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Variants',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setUpData();
                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                  isScrollControlled: true,
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: Container(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      child: Flexible(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Row(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Image.asset(
                                                    'assets/svg/barcode_reader.png',
                                                    height: 20.0,
                                                    width: 20.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Padding(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: 20.0)),
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Add Goods',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                        fontSize: 17.0),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Form(
                                                  key: _formKey,
                                                  child: Column(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          bottom: 20.0,
                                                          top: 40.0,
                                                        ),
                                                        child: TextFormField(
                                                          // initialValue:
                                                          //     variantDetails.name,
                                                          validator: (value) {
                                                            if (value
                                                                .trim()
                                                                .isEmpty) {
                                                              return 'Enter Name';
                                                            }
                                                            return null;
                                                          },
                                                          onChanged: (value) =>
                                                              variantDetails.name =
                                                                  value,
                                                          decoration:
                                                              InputDecoration(
                                                            border:
                                                                OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                            hintText: 'Name',
                                                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                                fontSize: 13.0),
                                                            hintMaxLines: 1,
                                                            contentPadding:
                                                                EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                                    20.0,
                                                                    8.0,
                                                                    20.0,
                                                                    8.0),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          bottom: 10.0,
                                                        ),
                                                        child: TextFormField(
                                                          // initialValue:
                                                          //     variantDetails
                                                          //         .description,
                                                          onChanged: (value) =>
                                                              variantDetails
                                                                      .description =
                                                                  value,
                                                          validator: (value) {
                                                            if (value
                                                                .trim()
                                                                .isEmpty) {
                                                              return 'Enter Description';
                                                            }
                                                            return null;
                                                          },
                                                          decoration:
                                                              InputDecoration(
                                                            border:
                                                                OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                            hintText: 'Description',
                                                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                                fontSize: 13.0),
                                                            hintMaxLines: 1,
                                                            contentPadding:
                                                                EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                                    20.0,
                                                                    15.0,
                                                                    20.0,
                                                                    15.0),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .spaceAround,
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                          Expanded(
                                                            child: TextFormField(
                                                              // initialValue:
                                                              //     variantDetails
                                                              //         .price,
                                                              onChanged: (value) =>
                                                                  variantDetails
                                                                          .price =
                                                                      value,
                                                              validator: (value) {
                                                                if (value
                                                                    .trim()
                                                                    .isEmpty) {
                                                                  return 'Enter Price';
                                                                }
                                                                return null;
                                                              },
                                                              keyboardType:
                                                                  TextInputType
                                                                      .phone,
                                                              decoration:
                                                                  InputDecoration(
                                                                border:
                                                                    OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                                hintText: 'Price',
                                                                hintStyle:
                                                                    TextStyle(
                                                                        fontSize:
                                                                            13.0),
                                                                hintMaxLines: 1,
                                                                contentPadding:
                                                                    EdgeInsets
                                                                        .fromLTRB(
                                                                            20.0,
                                                                            15.0,
                                                                            20.0,
                                                                            15.0),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          Padding(
                                                              padding:
                                                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                      left: 10.0)),
                                                          Expanded(
                                                            child: TextFormField(
                                                              // initialValue:
                                                              //     variantDetails
                                                              //         .nonTax,
                                                              decoration:
                                                                  InputDecoration(
                                                                border:
                                                                    OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                                hintText:
                                                                    'Inclusive of GST',
                                                                hintStyle:
                                                                    TextStyle(
                                                                        fontSize:
                                                                            13.0),
                                                                hintMaxLines: 1,
                                                                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons
                                                                    .arrow_drop_down),
                                                                contentPadding:
                                                                    EdgeInsets
                                                                        .fromLTRB(
                                                                            20.0,
                                                                            15.0,
                                                                            20.0,
                                                                            15.0),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  )),
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Net Price',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                        fontSize: 17.0),
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    '0',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                        fontSize: 17.0),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Total',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                        fontSize: 17.0),
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    '0',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                        color: Colors.black,
                                                        fontSize: 17.0),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
                                              ElevatedButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    trySubmit(context);
                                                  },
                                                  child: Text('UPDATE'))
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ));
                                  });
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: isVisible,
                    child: new ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return new ExpandableListView('Variant $index', ItemList);
                      },
                      itemCount: variantsList.length,
                    ),
                  )
              
                ],
              ),
            ));
```

//Here is the expandable list where i am showing my listview

```
class ExpandableListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<VariantDetails> variantList;

  ExpandableListView(this.title, this.variantList);

  @override
  _ExpandableListViewState createState() =>
      new _ExpandableListViewState(this.title, this.variantList);
}

class _ExpandableListViewState extends State<ExpandableListView> {
  bool expandFlag = false;
  final String title;
  final List<VariantDetails> variantList;
  _ExpandableListViewState(this.title, this.variantList);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0),
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  widget.title,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                ),
                new IconButton(
                    icon: new Container(
                      height: 20.0,
                      width: 20.0,
                      child: new Center(
                        child: new Icon(
                          expandFlag
                              ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                              : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        expandFlag = !expandFlag;
                      });
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new ExpandableContainer(
              expanded: expandFlag,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Container(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'Edit Variants',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(14),
                                  fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      //  Dismissible(key: Key(variantList[index]), child: child)
                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                                Icon(Icons.edit),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
                        Row(
                          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Name',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                        fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                                Text('Price',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                        fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                                Text('Description',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                        fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                                Text('Price Type',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                        fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                                Text('Non-taxable',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                        fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                                Text('Code Type',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                        fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                                Text('Stock Keeping Unit',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                        fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                                Text('Net Price',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                        fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                                Text('Tax',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'poppins',
                                        fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                                        color: Colors.black)),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(variantList[index].description),
                                Text(variantList[index].description),
                                Text(variantList[index].description),
                                Text(variantList[index].description),
                                Text(variantList[index].description),
                                Text(variantList[index].description),
                                Text(variantList[index].description),
                                Text(variantList[index].description),
                                Text(variantList[index].description),
                              ],
                            ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ));
                },
                itemCount: variantList.length,
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am implementing listview in my flutter application and whenever i add items in variantsList the new added item is reflecting in all the index of a list.

for example i am adding A
variantsList[0]='A'

Now i am adding another value B
The result which i am getting is

```
variantsList[0]='B',
variantsList[1]='B',
```

Expecting result

```
variantsList[0]='A',
variantsList[1]='B',
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `variantDetails`? How are you adding items to `variantsList`?

Comment: You should not call setState after pop

Comment: Details are not enough, add more information to get what you want ?!

Comment: add your code for listview !

Comment: Dart's List  has a method called `add`, from which you can simply add the items !  eg.: `variantsList.add('B')`

Comment: @AmeerAmjed please check above edited code

Comment: @enzo please check above edited code

Comment: @HasanAbbasi Please check above edited code

Comment: Show your code of adding data to the list

Comment: @OMiShah please check above edited code

Answer (score 0):

**According to my understanding, you mean deleting similar list data?
you have two way:-**

1. check data befor add to list if found use :-

```
if(!variantsList.contains('B'))
{//not found add data to list
variantsList.add('B');
}
```

2.Use end result  **toSet** and then **toList**

```
  variantsList = variantsList.toSet().toList();
```

Hope hlep you.

Comment: @Ammer Amjed my question is when adding multiple items in list the recently added item overrites all the index in the list